# Error Using Two FindNext

Tags: vba

This code has two range.find/findnext to search for values and related values in a list of parent/child values.

A dictionary is created of unique values for the parent value, then the range find is used in two loops using the dictionary as parent.

```
Sub tablaplana()
  Call SET_VAR
  '# FIND UNIQUE REGION CENTERS
  ' Dim region As Range
  ' Dim district As Range
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  With ws(3)
      r = 2
    x = 2
    Do Until x >= .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        jnum = .Cells(x, 3)
        jtype = .Cells(x, 4)
        jname = .Cells(x, 6)
        If jtype = "R" And InStr(1, jname, "REGION ADMIN") Then
            If Not dict.Exists(jnum) Then
                dict.Add jnum, jname
                Debug.Print x
            End If
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    '# FIND ALL SUB-SUB-VALUES VALUES OF PARENT UNIQUE VALUES
    For Each k In dict.Keys
        s = 0
        Set region = .Range("C:C").Find(k, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not region Is Nothing Then
            regionfirst = region.Address
            Do
                Set district = .Range("C:C").Find(.Cells(region.Row, 1), LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not district Is Nothing Then
                    districtfirst = district.Address
                    Do
                        '# ADD VALUES TO REPORT SHEET
                        ws(1).Cells(r, 1) = .Cells(district.Row, 1) 'sub-sub number
                        ws(1).Cells(r, 2) = .Cells(region.Row, 6) 'parent name
                        ws(1).Cells(r, 3) = .Cells(region.Row, 3) 'parent number
                        ws(1).Cells(r, 4) = .Cells(district.Row, 6) 'sub name
                        ws(1).Cells(r, 5) = .Cells(district.Row, 3) 'sub number
                        ws(1).Cells(r, 6) = .Cells(district.Row, 5) 'sub-sub name
                        Set district = .Range("C:C").FindNext(district)
                        r = r + 1
                    Loop While Not district Is Nothing And district.Address <> districtfirst
                End If
                Set region = .Range("C:C").FindNext(region)
            Loop While Not region Is Nothing And region.Address <> regionfirst
        End If
      Next k
  End With
End Sub
```

Using two Range.Find and FindNext is causing error. Upon reaching the second FindNext(region) the returned value is equal to the first FindNext(district) even though it is looking for Region.

Also dim as region creates error message at same lime.

Comment: I think the problem might be because `.Range("C:C")` creates new range. You can try setting that to a range `Set rngC = .Range("C:C")` and then call the finds on it `rngC.Find` and `rngC.FindNext`

Comment: Actually, as far as I know both of the `.FindNext` will look for the same value that was passed to the last call to `.Find` before `.FindNext`, so you will have to use something like `.Find(k, After:=region)` instead of `.FindNext(region)`

Comment: @Slai, I believe you are correct. Changed line to Set region = rng.Find(region, after:=region) and it all seems to work !!